# Python programming .....Basics

Tags: python, python-3.x

Thank you, I have some doubt in python programming like

1. Difference in between module,library,package.
2. What is difference in between built in and keyword.
   Eg: None,True  is Builtins not keywords.
3. What is the use of writing the code(to call main method)
   `if __name__=__main__:main`
   rather than simple call `main()`
4. Can I access the attributes of class,using class name 
   like below code

Code:

```
class A:  
    atri=9  
    def method(self):  
       print 'This is method'      

def my():
    print 'attribute access using Class name ',A.atri
    print 'method calling using Class name ',A.method()

my()
```

Comment: This is multiple questions.  You should ask them separately

Comment: And you should consider reading the tutorial as well as the existing questions that already cover each of your questions.

Comment: And you tagged it Python 3, but your code is Python 2. :-)

Answer (score 4):

1. A module is a Python file. A package is a directory that has an `__init__.py` file. It behaves almost like it's a module, although it's a directory. A library is a reusable module or package.
2. A keyword is a reserved word which you can't assign to. A builtin is a variable that is available "by default" so to speak. They are listed in the `__builtins__` variable. In Python 2 `True` and `False` are indeed builtins, but not keywords. In Python 3 they are both builtins and keywords.
3. It allows you to use the module as a library, without calling main() when you import it.
4. Yes you can.